# Using highcharts with Sencha ext js 6

Tags: extjs, highcharts, extjs6

I have been trying to do some search's to find a way to use highcharts with sencha ext js 6.

So far i have been able to find a plugin which according to the below link works on ext 4

https://market.sencha.com/extensions/highcharts

Would this work on ext js 6 with the latest version of highcharts?

Or is there any other way to use highcharts with sencha?

Comment: Did you test at least?

Comment: No. I am new to ext js and i haven't found any resource online to use it with ext js 6.

Comment: I am unsure of where to place this plugin and how will it get loaded so i can use it inside my classic app.https://market.sencha.com/extensions/highcharts

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to consider the included chart package before trying to include an external library.
See http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/?charts=true#all if it suit your needs.

If this is not the case,
then to include the highcharts extension, Joe Kuan as explain this in his blog : https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/building-extjshighcharts-application-with-sencha-cmd-tool/
And if it's not done already, i suggest to read:
this : http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/extjs/cmd_app.html
and this http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/index.html : 
Before :)

Hope it helps!